# How would I convert a ios UIView animation to a video

Tags: ios, animation, video, uiview

How would I convert a ios UIView animation to a video? Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use the AVMutableComposition. You can use AVAssets inside it to store the video (i.e, record). For recording the view you are using a mutable composition then wat you can do is maybe add the layer of the avplayer as the layer of the view which you are trying to make the video of. So ideally the interactions happening with the avplayerlayer is most likely to happen form the view layer itself. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try iPhone/iPad simulator on Mac and capture the screen.

Comment: Actually I want to make an app on iphone that exports the UIView animation to a video file, so I need to do that programmatically